# JqueryUI Datepicker not working ASP.NET MVC5

Tags: asp.net, jquery-ui, asp.net-mvc-5, jquery-ui-datepicker

I installed jqueryUI combined

```
    Install-Package jQuery.UI.Combined
```

Bundled them in bundleconfig like so:

bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryui").Include(
        "~/Scripts/jquery-ui-{version}.js"));

```
    bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/themes/base/css").Include(
      "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.core.css",
      "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.resizable.css",
      "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.selectable.css",
      "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.accordion.css",
      "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.autocomplete.css",
      "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.button.css",
      "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.dialog.css",
      "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.slider.css",
      "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.tabs.css",
      "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.datepicker.css",
      "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.progressbar.css",
      "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.theme.css"));
```

My view:

```
<div class="input-group input-group-sm center-box">
                    <div class="text-font">Date of birth</div>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.DateOfBirth, new { @class = "date-picker" })
```

and scirpt:

```
          <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        // This will make every element with the class "date-picker" into a DatePicker element
        $('#DateOfBirth').datepicker();
    })
</script>
                </div>
```

[And it looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ppzk7.jpg)

Any thoughts?

Comment: Make sure you are using referencing **jquery** before **jquery-ui**  e.g.,
`<link rel="stylesheet" href="@Url.Content("//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css")">
<script src="@Url.Content("//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js")"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.js")"></script>`

Answer (score 0):

- make sure you added the jquery css and js reference correctly (better you can use cdn link)
- try giving that textbox id with "DateOfBirth" like that 
  @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.DateOfBirth, new { @Id= "DateOfBirth", class = "date-picker" })

Answer (score 0):

Though its too late for you. might help someone who might be looking.

render 
@Styles.Render("~/Content/themes/base/css") in layout page.